# Capturar elemento de array javascript

Tags: javascript

Olá, como posso capturar o nome maria do id 2?

```
listform: [
  {
    id: "1",
    nome: "juana"
  },
  {
    id: "2"
    nome: "maria"
  },
  {
    id: "3"
    nome: "carlos"
  } 
]
```

Comment: Você quer fazer a busca pelo `id` ou pelo `nome`?

Comment: @Marconi quero recuperar só os segundos valores do meio que no caso é o id 2 e o nome maria

Comment: Não tenho certeza se entendi mas pode fazer um loop na lista e retornar o objeto (ou uma propriedade dele) cujo id/nome seja o desejado

Comment: Josimara, gostaria de saber se a minha resposta tem ajudado você

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?!
Quando falamos sobre Array, podemos tratar sobre arrays unidimensionais e multidimensionais...

Um array unidimensional é um array que contém "apenas um nível de índices", por exemplo:

```
//Criando um array unidimensional
var meu_array = new Array();
meu_array[0] = 'Hello World'; 
meu_array
```

[image: Imagem representativa de um Array unidimensional]

Note que na imagem acima o 0 circulado é referente ao indice unidimencional (temos apenas um indice para cada "espaço" no array e mais nenhum ligado à ele.

Já um array multidimensional é um array que contém outros arrays dentro dele, por exemplo:

```
// Criando um array multidimensional
var meu_array = new Array();
meu_array[0] = new Array("id:1","nome:juana");
meu_array[1] = new Array("id:2","nome:maria");
meu_array[2] = new Array("id:3","nome:carlos");
meu_array
```

[image: Imagem representativa de um Array multidimencional]

Note que na imagem acima, o índice 0 está apontando para mais (2) indices, ou seja, além 
cada de "espaço" no índice primario do array, temos mais 2 "espaços" no índice secundário.

**Lembrando que a contagem de índices para Arrays começam sempre do número 0 em ordem crescente.**

O listform
do qual você está utilizando se enquadra no tipo de array *multidimensional*:

Então, capturar apenas no nome "maria" do índice 1, podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
 meu_array[1][1]
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 3):

No seu código o array está sendo definido incorretamente, a atribuição é com `=` e estão faltando algumas vírgulas.

Caso você saiba a posição do objeto, poderá capturar facilmente com `listform[1].nome`, julgando que a posição começa no 0, maria está no objeto de posição 1, exemplo.

```js
let listform = [
  {
    id: "1",
    nome: "juana"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    nome: "maria"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    nome: "carlos"
  } 
];

console.log(listform[1].nome);
```

Caso queira pegar o nome maria baseado no seu id `2`, basta usar a propriedade indexOf juntamente com um looping, exemplo...

**map**

```js
let listform = [
  {
    id: "1",
    nome: "juana"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    nome: "maria"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    nome: "carlos"
  } 
];

key = listform.map(function(e) { return e.id; }).indexOf('2');

if(key != -1)
    console.log(listform[key].nome)
else
    console.log('Não foi possível encontrar o id')
```

Caso você queira um suporte maior entre os browsers, basta adaptar o método para um looping mais simples.

Answer (score 3):

Uma das formas mais diretas de obter o resultado que quer é utilizando [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) que lhe permite passar uma função com a busca que pretende fazer e devolve o primeiro elemento que seja válido para essa busca. No seu caso tem de efetuar a busca através do `id`:

```
let pessoa = listform.find(p => p.id === "2");
```

Veja a funcionar:

```js
const listform = [
  {
    id: "1",
    nome: "juana"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    nome: "maria"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    nome: "carlos"
  } 
];

let pessoa = listform.find(p => p.id === "2");
console.log(pessoa.nome);
```

É importante mencionar que neste momento o `find` não é suportado no antigo Internet Explorer no entanto a própria página da documentação tem o *polyfill* que pode utilizar se precisar desse suporte.